# Translations missing

Tags: translation

I've checked many times on transifex in order not to forget important elements and, eg, all household occurrences are correctly translated to italian.
I'm using 4.7.19 on Joomla 3.6.5 (or 3.7.2), php 5.6.
I've also downloaded the .po files and combined to .mo with poedit.
But there are words that keep being in english, for example on the left sidebar, the dropdown menu for adding new items, still shows household, individual and organization in english. And there are other words everywhere that don't show italian translation.
Even trying to substitute words does not produce results, have a look here:
http://nimb.ws/rxIJQe
Does anyone know if there's a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You can download daily builded translation files from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-l10n-core/mo/it_IT/civicrm.mo.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky translation "issue" as far as I know. When you install CiviCRM in one language all the system strings are set with the string status of the translation at the moment of the installation. For this reason when you have an incomplete CiviCRM language translation is common to find some system strings untranslated and although you try to ammend it translating it later they will persist in English.

The only way that I've found to overcome this is to manually overwrite system strings. You can found many of them at civicrm/admin/options?reset=1. E.g. to change contact types names you have to to edit admin/options/subtype?reset=1 options.

Comment: Thank you Francesc, I've delved deeper in those pages (done that many times, but for some reason I overlooked it) I've found the three items under Contact types, they seemed translated on the list and only after modifying one by one the untranslated records went out...

Comment: Now what I can't find is the "New" prefix under dropdown menu http://jmp.sh/jzHTzdI

Comment: They are menu items and can be edited here /civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1

Comment: Anyway in our instances this "new" strings for the three main types of contacts are translated. Make sure you do not have any untranslated string in the Italian translation on transifex.